# Create a new dict with means from a dict of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, mean, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary like:

```
dict = {'abc':{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
'bla':{'a':0,'b':9},
'ind':{'b':3,'c':4}
 }
```

And I want to use list or dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary which contains every inner key, and then the mean across all values for that inner key, e.g.:

```
result = {'a':(1+0/2),'b':(2+9+3/3),'c':(3+4/2)}
```

How can I do this? I was trying to experiment with

```
import numpy as np

result = {key: np.mean([inner_value for key,inner_value for inner_dict.items() for outer_key,inner_dict in dict.items()]) for key,inner_value for inner_dict.items() for outer_key,inner_dict in dict.items()}
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you specifically asked for dictionary/list comprehension, but I'm not sure it's possible to solve this problem with only those tools in an efficient way.

I think the code below is clear and reasonably succinct:

```
from collections import defaultdict

outer = {
    'abc': { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
    'bla': { 'a': 0, 'b': 9},
    'ind': { 'b': 3, 'c': 4},
}

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for inner in outer.values():
    for key, value in inner.items():
        grouped[key].append(value)

means = { key: sum(values) / len(values)
          for key, values in grouped.items() }

print(means) # {'c': 3.5, 'a': 0.5, 'b': 4.666666666666667}
```